# Insert an element at each index - Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html

So I have an array that I want to loop through, and at each index I want to insert a string.

I based my loop on the below code, hoping it would work. But each time it breaks my browser, any idea why this is?

```
//code works fine
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    i = 0;
while (i <= array.length) {
    array.splice(i, 0, 0);
    i += 2;
}
console.log(array);


<h4>slappin' and pampering the modern way</h4>

//problematic code
function get_nodes() {
    let el = document.querySelector("h4");
    let childnods = el.innerText;
    let newArray = childnods.split(' ');

    let i = 0;
    while (i <= newArray.length) {
        newArray.splice(i, 0, 'test');
            i += 2;
    }
    
    console.log(newArray);
    }

get_nodes()

Expected result would be:
newArray = ["test", "slappin'", "test", "and", "test", "pampering", "test", "the", "test", "modern","test", "way", "test"]
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you explain bit more on it??

Comment: added the expected result, thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you have written the correct code for the expected output, just you need to replace the `array.splice(i, 0, 'test');` to `newArray.splice(i, 0, 'test');` in your while loop.

Comment: I did that, and my browser is still breaking. I still would like to find out why that is.

Comment: Is there any console error or you are not getting proper output?

Comment: I don't get any output in the console. The browser seems to go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can split your string on space and use `array#flatMap` to add `test` word after each word.

```js
const statement = document.querySelector("h4").innerText,
      result = statement.split(' ').flatMap(word => [word, 'test']),
      output = ['test'].concat(result);

console.log(output);
```

```html
<h4>slappin' and pampering the modern way</h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about :

```js
let el = document.querySelector("h4");
let childnods = el.innerText;
let arrayOfItems = childnods.split(' ');

console.log(arrayOfItems);

let newString = arrayOfItems.join(",test,");

let newArray = newString.split(',');


console.log(newArray);
```

```html
<h4>slappin' and pampering the modern way</h4>
```

Make sure that you don't have `,` in your original text .

Then you may add `test` as the first and last items .